# Hiding shopping cart when hovering away from both cart and the tab that opened it

Tags: jquery

I implemented a shopping cart using two divs. A 'cart' div that contains the cart image and 'cart_items' div containing cart items.
I can make cart_items slideDown when clicking on the cart image. I can hide cart_items when hovering it then leaving it, the problems I have are:

1. I can not hide cart_items when clicking the cart then mouseleaving it without entering cart_items.
2. I can not hover over both, cart and cart_items without preventing cart_items from hiding.

cart and cart_items are in two adjacent divs.

HTML

```
<div id='header'>
    <div id='cart'><img src='cart.png'></div>
</div>

<div id='container'>
    <div id='cart_items'> contain items that will be pulled from database </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
 $('#cart').click(function(){
    $('#cart_items').slideDown("300");
 });

 $('#cart_items').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#cart_items').hide();
 });
```

I did lots of online search and I added many jQuery mouseenter and mouseleave to both divs but somehow the events were cancelling each other.

Comment: Can u simulate the same on jsfiddle

Comment: Working as it exists: http://jsfiddle.net/uedyW/

Comment: The divs header and container a part of another div ? Can you try the using the parent divs ? (Instead of cart, use header). Just saw Marks jsfiddle. So can you try this on other browsers ? If you debugging the browser, does the console show any js errors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you bring your cart_item div within the cart div, and then define your mouseleave function on the cart div, it should do what you are looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/uedyW/3/

```
<div id='header'>
    <div id='cart'>
        <img src='cart.png'>
        <div id='cart_items'>contain items that will be pulled from database</div>
    </div>
</div>

 $('#cart').click(function () {
     $('#cart_items').slideDown("300");
 });

 $('#cart').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#cart_items').hide();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Check where you move to. Also change the selector to #container for the mouse leave:

```
$('#container').mouseleave(function (e) {
            if (e.toElement.id != 'cart')
                $('#cart_items').hide();
        });
```

Comment: Tried updating the fiddle. Not sure if it worked there: http://jsfiddle.net/uedyW/1/
Does work with suggested solution on my local machine

Comment: you did not put the (e) in the function.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap them both and then use that outer container:

```
<div id="outerContainer">
    <div id='header'>
        <div id='cart'>
            <img src='cart.png'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='container'>
        <div id='cart_items'>contain items that will be pulled from database</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code

```
 $('#cart').click(function () {
     $('#cart_items').slideDown("300");
 });

 $('#outerContainer').mouseleave(function (e) {
      $('#cart_items').hide();
 });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/uedyW/6/